# An old anime (1998-2007) about a guy living with a couple of girls under the same roof

Tags: love-hina

I'm looking for an old anime but can't find it.
I watched it as a kid, around the time Dragon Ball Z got popular in the West too.

It's about a guy (I believe with glasses), that starts living in a house with a couple of girls. Most of the stories revolve around crushes of one another, but there are no-sexual encounters, just a lot of mistakes in which he sees them naked accidentally and gets kicked around a lot. Actually he has a crush on the oldest one of the girls in the house.

A lot of the anime is revolving around the local university/school. He pretends to be in the university, but actually isn't, while I believe the oldest girl in the house is taking the entrance exams.

There is no fighting in the game, nor any sexual content.
I believe it existed in manga form too.

I can't remember more. Does anyone know which anime I'm talking about?

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like **Love Hina.** Some relevant plot points that matches your description:

- The main character wears glasses.
- He lives with other girls in a hotel, trying to get into the University of Tokyo. He failed the entrance exams twice and still attempts to get into it.
- One of the girls is taking entrance exams to the same university.
- He does accidentally see other girls naked at times.
- There are no explicit sexual encounter, at least, none that I know of.

I'm not sure about him having a crush on the oldest one. Let us know if this is the correct answer or not.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Hina

Comment: While "guy living with large group of girls, crushes abound, no sex but lots of accidental nudity resulting in grievous bodily harm" describes practically every rom com anime of the 90s, Love Hina is probably the ur-example.